# how to change unicode to string in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

I am getting NoReverseMatch because I'm getting a unicode instead of a string, is there a way I could turn unicode to string in the templates?

this is my normal hyperlink

```
# hyperlink in templates
    {% for lst in mylist %}
        <a href="{% url "url_list" lst.user.username %}"> {{ lst.user.username }} </a>
    {% endfor %}
```

how can I do lst.user.username.encode("utf-8") inside a hyperlink?

```
# hyperlink in templates
    {% for lst in mylist %}
        <a href="{% url "url_list" lst.user.username.encode("utf-8") %}"> {{ lst.user.username }} </a>
    {% endfor %}



# Url
    url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/list/$', url_list.as_view(), name='url_list'),
```

Edit:

I changed the regex in my url and it's working now.

```
url(r'^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/list/$', url_list.as_view(), name='url_list'),
```

Comment: Unicode is definitely not the problem here. You should post the exact error message and traceback.

Answer (score 1):

The django will render unicode string to utf-8 automatically.

maybe the issue is the url routing? try to add `ur` before the regex patterns

```
url(ur'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/list/$', url_list.as_view(), name='url_list'),
```

Comment: adding ur did not work but your post did help me check on my url. Thank You, I'll add point to you.